How to acces element in std::list and change its value?
struct Student 
{
    string Name;
    string ID;
};

So I have a structure in which I have the given strings.
void Insert(list<Student>& List, int index, Student info)
{
    if (index< 0 || index>= List.size() || List.empty() == true)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {

    }
}

In the "else" area, I want to access the element with the given index and change the value in it to info.
I have tried with the following lines, and it didn't work?
std::list<Student>::iterator it = List.begin();
std::advance(it, index);
it = info;


If you are trying to insert a new element in the list then use the member function insert of the list.

An iterator it pointer-like. You need to dereference it to access the referred element. Try *it = info, or in this case you probably want *it = std::move(info); if you don't use info later. Note that if you want to access an element by index, using an std::list is very likely a bad choice for a container.

If you are looking to access a list with an index then you are using the wrong data structure. A vector instead of a list would be better.

Your code should be *it = info;

Thanks everyone, the "*it = info" fixed the problem :D


in the "else" area I want to access the element with the given index and change the value in it to info [...]

You were almost there. You have to dereference the iterator to access the underlying element. That means, you have to
*it = info;
^^ --> dereferencing

or better move the info into it, if the info is not further used inside the function scope.
*it = std::move(info);
^^ --> dereferencing


That being said, if you want to access the iterator by index, there are better alternatives, such as std::array(if the array size is fixed and known by compile time, std::vector (if the array size is dynamic), etc.)
